# Troubleshooting ssh key for gitlab clone/push/pull

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab

I've tried following solutions, so I did [generated new](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) `ssh key` for my `gitlab` account, when I do `ssh -v git@gitlab.com` I've got `Permissions denied (publickey).`.

Second solution is [Working with non-default SSH key pair paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths), so I've generated new key for that and my `~/.ssh/config` is looking like this

```
  # GitLab.com server                                                         
  Host gitlab.com
  RSAAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub
```

Both key's are added to my `gitlab` account, and when I try to [troubleshoot](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/admin/articles/troubleshooting-ssh-permission-denied-publickey/) ssh with:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub -p 122 git@gitlab.com` I've got nothing, literally when I type that to the terminal nothing is happening, and when I type `shh -vvv git@gitlab.com` the result is this:

```
  OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/petar/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/petar/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for gitlab.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/petar/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/petar/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.167.219.168
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/petar/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/petar/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub (0x562dd6bb8c80), explicit, agent
debug2: key: ppilipovic84@gmail.com (0x562dd6bbde10), agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/petar/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ppilipovic84@gmail.com
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can someone please explain me how to fix this?

Comment: Try using `-vvv` for ultra-verbose output

Comment: I did, updated my question, it's like he is not finding my key, this part `debug1: identity file /home/petar/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory` but I don't get it why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IdentityFile` should point to the private key, not to the public key:

```
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
```

Comment: true, and I did `eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/other_id_rsa` but I'm still getting `permission denied (public key)`

Comment: Which one of all that keys you are using all around the question is that one that was added into gitlab?  Please, do not generate any more keys and use that single one that you added to the gitlab.

Comment: wait, I'm using git `~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab`, the output of the `ssh -vvv git@gitlab` is in the question, I'm not generating any more keys, but I don't understand why he is not finding my key in `~/.ssh/`

Comment: It finds both of the keys, but both of them are rejected by the server. This means they are probably not configured on the server correctly.

Comment: hm, I've just added them to settings, and title them, they are starting with `ssh-rsa` and ending with my mail like `== ppilipovic84@gmail.com`, I'm will  accept this because `congif` file was miss configure.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jakuje suggested I was making a mistake in `IdentityFile`, but also I didn't know that this `gitlab` is staged on a private server so, if you want to clone a repository from private `gitlab` you need to do this

`git clone git@ip_address_of_the_server:SomeName/ProjectName.git` and you will be able to successfully clone the repository, but you first need to add [ssh](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html#how-to-create-your-ssh-keys) key to your `gitlab` profile.

You can also `git clone` it using `http`, then you need to do this

`http://server_ip_address/SomeName/ProjectName.git`, and you will be prompt for your `username` and `password`.